# GParted: Merging two partitions

Tags: gparted, ram

I want to merge my sda7 with the unallocated space. However, I am not sure how to do it. 
This is the Memory allocated in my device.
[Gparted Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAam9.png)

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### After Backing Up the Whole Drive

- Boot Live Ubuntu USB or DVD.
- Open GParted.
- Right click on sda7 and select Resize/Move.
- Stretch the partition to fill all the space in the drop down.
- Click on the little check mark to Apply All Operations.

If you had needed to increase the Windows partition size, you would do it in Windows Disk Manager.

Comment: OP needs to boot live-USB to do that.

Comment: Yes, of course, thank you. I guess it could also be done using a UNetbootin frugal install in Windows, (Hard Disk Install Mode), If USB drive is not handy. https://sourceforge.net/p/unetbootin/wiki/installmodes/